# How to demonstrate that z=x+y follows a normal distribution?

Tags: statistics

How can I demonstrate that, if I know that x and y follow a normal distribution $N(x, \mu_{1}, \sigma_{1}^{2})$ and $N(y, \mu_{2}, \sigma_{2}^{2})$, $z=x+y$ also follows a normal distribution $N(x+y, \mu_{1}+\mu_{2}, \sigma_{1}^{2}+\sigma_{2}^{2})$?

I started by writting:

$g(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dxf(x)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dyf(y)\delta(x+y-z)$

but I'm not sure if that's the correct way, as I reach to an integral hard to solve.

Comment: Are you allowed to use moment generating functions? Also, in general it is not true that X + Y will be normal. They have to be independent.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables is a good resource for proving the result in different ways. Proof using the moment generating functions is probably the simplest way, but you can do it using convolutions too

Comment: @Alborz thanks! that wikipedia link really helped!